# Await issue in foreach Gmail API

Tags: foreach, async-await, gmail-api

I need to authenticate multiple tokens of different users and get inbox mails. Here is the code

```
await configuredMails.forEach( async(mails) => {
        let token = mails.token;
        oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
        let inboxMails = await listInboxMails(oAuth2Client);
    });

listInboxMails = async (auth) => {
        const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth}); 
        await gmail.users.messages.list(      
          {        
            userId: 'me',        
            q: query,
            maxResults: 1    
          },async (err, res) => { 
                const messages = res.data.messages;      
                if (typeof messages != undefined && messages != undefined) {
                  await messages.forEach(async(message) => {
                    let messageID = message.id;
                    let threadID = message.threadId;
                    let threadDetails = await this.getThreadDetails(threadID);
                    if(threadDetails != null){
                        await gmail.users.messages.get(      
                          {        
                            userId: 'me',        
                            id: messageID   
                          },async(err, res) => { 
.....................
......................
```

Here issues is before executing the gmail.users.messages.get() function the loop is iterating. So the next token is setting. So it shows Requested entity not found error. Because the oAuth2Client is replacing

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to understand how your code works. To do that you need to understand how Authorization works.

Every request you send to the API which accesses private user data must contain a authorization header with a bearer token with an access token that contains enough permissions in order to perform the action.

in order to do this in code you must define a gmail service with the authorization for the user.  This being a single user.  Auth will contain the authorization credentials for the single user.  You will only be able to use this for one user.

```
const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth});
```

If you have credentials for more than one user then you will need to build the auth and the gmail service for each of those users.

Comment: If I removed the foreach and called the function seperately with a time delay of 5 seconds , its working. The problem is before completing the gmail api the loop is iterating. Tokens are overwriting I think